# Clarification on paper: "Information Flow in Entangled Quantum Systems" - David Deutsch and Patrick Hayden

Tags: quantum-computer

Referencing paper "Information Flow in Entangled Quantum Systems" by David Deutsch and Patrick Hayden, specifically the section concerning Quantum Teleportation:

http://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/9906/9906007.pdf

**Result (34)** on page 15 has the Y (2nd) observable as:

$\hat q_{5y}(4) = (cos(\theta)\hat\sigma_y + sin(\theta)\hat\sigma_z) \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_z$

To get to this state at time 4, along with qubits 2 and 3, qubit 5 has undergone a 'T' transformation detailed in **Result (33)**. This result shows the output of qubit 5, which is labelled $\hat q_m$ in the last of the 3 rows of description of the transformation as:

$\hat q_{my}(t+1) =  \hat q_{kz}(t).\hat q_{lz}(t).\hat q_{my}(t)$

Following the chain back to earlier results, we can see that the inputs to this are:

- $\hat q_{kz}(t)$ is qubit 2's Z observable $\hat q_{2z}(3)$ which **Result (32)** specifies as $(sin(\theta)\hat\sigma_y - cos(\theta)\hat\sigma_z) \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat 1 \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_x$
- $\hat q_{lz}(t)$ is qubit 3's Z observable $\hat q_{3z}(3)$ which **Result (32)** specifies as $-\hat\sigma_x \otimes \hat 1 \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_x \otimes \hat 1$
- $\hat q_{my}(t)$ is qubit 5's Y observable $\hat q_{5y}(3)$ which has not changed since $\hat q_{5y}(1)$ and **Result (30)** specifies as $\hat 1 \otimes \hat 1 \otimes \hat 1 \otimes -\hat\sigma_x \otimes \hat\sigma_y$

Dotting these all up (ignoring the identity $\hat 1$ terms) gives the result:

$\hat q_{5y}(4) = (sin(\theta)\hat\sigma_y - cos(\theta)\hat\sigma_z).(-\hat\sigma_x) \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_z . \hat\sigma_x .(-\hat\sigma_x) \otimes \hat\sigma_x . \hat\sigma_y$

Using **Result (2)** on page 3:

- In qubit 1, $\hat\sigma_y.\hat\sigma_x$ simplifies to $i\hat\sigma_z$
- In qubit 1, $\hat\sigma_z.\hat\sigma_x$ simplifies to $i\hat\sigma_y$
- In qubit 4, $\hat\sigma_x.\hat\sigma_x$ simplifies to $\hat 1$
- In qubit 5, $\hat\sigma_x.\hat\sigma_y$ simplifies to $i\hat\sigma_z$

Therefore, we have:

$\hat q_{5y}(4) = -(i sin(\theta)\hat\sigma_z - i cos(\theta)\hat\sigma_y)\otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes -\hat\sigma_z \otimes i\hat\sigma_z$

Collecting the constants $-1$ and $i$ out we have:

$\hat q_{5y}(4) = (cos(\theta)\hat\sigma_y - sin(\theta)\hat\sigma_z)\otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_z \otimes \hat\sigma_z$

This is different from **Result (34)**, I calculate $cos - sin$ rather than $cos + sin$. I've modelled this in Mathematica and worked through this carefully by hand as a double-check. Can someone explain the inconsistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **Result (2)** on page 3 to get:

> - In qubit 1, $\hat\sigma_y.\hat\sigma_x$ simplifies to $i\hat\sigma_z$
> - In qubit 1, $\hat\sigma_z.\hat\sigma_x$ simplifies to $i\hat\sigma_y$
> - In qubit 4, $\hat\sigma_x.\hat\sigma_x$ simplifies to $\hat 1$
> - In qubit 5, $\hat\sigma_x.\hat\sigma_y$ simplifies to $i\hat\sigma_z.$

Wouldn't it be better to use

- $\hat\sigma_y\hat\sigma_x=-i\hat\sigma_z$
- $\hat\sigma_z\hat\sigma_x=i\hat\sigma_y$
- $\hat\sigma_x\hat\sigma_x=\hat 1$
- $\hat\sigma_x\hat\sigma_y=i\hat\sigma_z$?

Since the latter are correct identities when juxtaposition is composition of operators.

Comment: Of course. Thanks ever so much for spotting that for me.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, my Mathematica model now works: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a25f16ba-dad5-43af-9952-d7f256606c05